# Solana Rent Exemption

Tags: solana

According to the [solana docs](https://docs.solana.com/developing/programming-model/accounts#rent-exemption)

> Alternatively, an account can be made entirely exempt from rent collection by depositing at least 2 years worth of rent.

Does this mean, that so long as you deposit 2 years worth of rent, your account can never be purged?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes correct, when you deposit more than 2 years of rent, your account is rent exempted. Actually most projects are using the rent exemption amount by default. There are not a lot of usecases where you would want to deposit less than the rent exemption amount since you can get your SOL back when you don't need the account anymore.

Comment: So what's even the purpose of having rent at all?

Comment: You can think of it as a mechanism to prevent people from ddosing the data storage. The more storage you require, the more SOL you need to lockup. Most blockchains including Ethereum has this mechanism, it's just not clearly stated as rent.

Comment: And how much is that in lamports per year per kB? The documentation goes as far as to say that the rent price is a fixed amount of lamports per kB per year but for reasons that are beyond my comprehension they don't say how much.